# How large can weights be when matching?

Tags: r, causality, matching

I am executing coarsened exact matching (CEM) in R using the `MatchIt` package. Below is the syntax for my project:

```
c_matched <- matchit(pko ~ lnatres + lgdppc + lpop + lmilper,
                     data = merged,
                     method = "cem",
                     estimand = "ATT")

c_matched <- match.data(c_matched)
```

However, when executing this code, I get some pretty large weights:

```
summary(c_matched$weights)

#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
# 0.3450  0.7838  0.8550  1.0000  1.0688  5.4619
```

In all the examples I have read on matching, weights have always ranged between 0 and 1. However, as noted from the summary statistics above, many of my values are *well* over 1. I am trying to figure out if I have an issue (and I'm pretty sure that I do), and if so, what is the root of the issue?

Comment: Weights are not usually bounded between 0 and 1, on the contrary. I think you might be confusing weights with their corresponding _propensity scores_ - which are probabilities (bounded between 0 and 1). But the _weights_ are the inverse of these probabilities. Specifically, for ATT - the weight for the treated units is 1, and the weights for the untreated units are the odds $\frac{p}{1-p}$. **Edit**: Seems like [Matchit's documentation covers this](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/reference/matchit.html#how-matching-weights-are-computed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MatchIt output using Coarsened Exact Matching](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/499397/matchit-output-using-coarsened-exact-matching). The documentation explains everything you need to know about the weights.